# add newline after dnd without completely rewriting the class

Tags: java, swing

I've been trying to figure out how to approach getting a jtextarea to add a newline after a drag and drop into it.  I was wondering if there's a simple way to do this without having to rewrite any of the basic dnd stuff, like transferhandler.  Maybe through a listener on the Jtextarea?

thanks

For example, after dragging and dropping some text into a Jtextarea, a new line would be inserted right after the inserted text.
Basically, the cursor would be moved to a new line instead of at the end of the inserted text.

Update:
So I tried just adding a mouselistener to add a newline after releasing the mouse but it doesn't work because the when dragging and dropping into the textarea the program isn't in focus.

Comment: Please provide relevant code for everyone to understand clearly what you are asking. Please refer [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to get a better understanding.

Comment: The answer is mostly likely no

Comment: Add a new line where..which IDE are you using for dnd...You have to give us more info..

Comment: a newline in the text of the jtextarea.  the IDE is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

So the best way to approach adding a new line after inserting some text is to just to add a DocumentListener to the Jtextarea.

Comment: No it's not, as you have discovered from your new question. The problem is you're mutating the `Document` from within a mutating event, which can cause no end of issues. The other problem is, you don't know why the `Document` is been updated, there's not enough context available. The better solution would be to write your own `TransferHandler`, but instead of accepting the "best" solution, you're attempting to find the "easiest" solution, which often leads to more hacks and unnecessary work arounds.

Comment: I suggest you start by having a look at [TransferHandler](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/transferhandler.html) instead